# Making a boxplot from binary data in R

Tags: r, binary, boxplot, categorical-data

I have a binary variable of signal present or not (1,0) and a categorical variable (Transmitter High and Transmitter Low). I'd like to show a boxplot displaying the probability of 1 occurring for each category. Hopefully showing the box for High to have a greater chance to hear the signal than low. How do I get a boxplot to show the likelihood of 1 occurring for each of my categories?

Here is an example of my data:

```
155          0     Top
156          1     Bot
157          1     Top
158          1     Bot
159          1     Top
160          1     Bot
161          1     Top
162          0     Bot
163          1     Top
164          1     Top
165          1     Bot
166          1     Top
167          1     Bot
168          1     Top
169          1     Top
170          1     Bot
171          1     Bot
172          1     Top
173          1     Bot
174          1     Bot
175          1     Top
176          1     Top
177          1     Bot
178          1     Top
179          0     Bot
180          0     Top`
```

Comment: What is your question? It's not really obvious.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. Does this make it any better?

Comment: Can you post example of your data?

Comment: Does that help?